# How to say that one set is the smallest containing another set?

Tags: notation

Imagine that we have a collection of sets $\cal C$, let $S\notin \cal C$ and $A \in \cal C$.

In algebra, topology, etc... we often see statements like " ----- is the smallest set containing -----", but I'm always not sure how to formalize these kinds of statements. How can I write that $A$ is the smallest set in $\cal C$ containing the set $S$? How can we measure the "length" of these sets in order to say that one is smaller than the other?

Comment: For sets of discrete elements $|S|$ is the cardinality or "size" of a set—the number of its elements.

Comment: But, for example, If I'm talking about sets in $\Bbb R$, how can I say that some set is the smallest set containing another? All intervals in $\Bbb R$ have the same cardinality @DavidG.Stork

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this use we order sets by inclusion, so you would say that $A$ is in $\mathcal C$, contains $S$, and all other sets in $\mathcal C$ that contain $S$ also contain $A$.

Comment: So, $S \subset B \Rightarrow A \subset B$?

Comment: Yes, for all sets $B \subset \mathcal C$

Answer (score 1):

The statement usually means the property $$A\in\mathcal C\land A\supseteq S\land (\forall B\in \mathcal C,(A\subseteq B\lor S\nsubseteq B))$$
id est that $A\in\mathcal C$ is a set containing $S$ and, for all other sets $B\in\mathcal C$ which contain $S$, $A\subseteq B$.

Personally, I would not use the word "smallest" when I'm referring to cardinality. I would say "of least cardinality" (or "least size", or "least measure", or "least greatest lower bund of the sine of an odd integer contained in it"...).

Comment: So is this the same as saying that if $\mathcal {P} = \{U \in \mathcal C : S \subseteq U\}$, then $\bigcap_{U \in \mathcal P} U = A$?

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães There is one if and only if $\bigcap\mathcal P\in\mathcal C$, in which case $A=\bigcap \mathcal P$.